# how to iterate through strings to dynamically add to Hash Map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap

I am a semi new at this but I was doing this example: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem .
If there's a collection of strings separated by spaces that come from STDIN , how would I add them to a Map().  I know how to iterate through an array and add those values to a map but how can you iterate through a non-array?

Comment: can you provide the example collection?

Answer (score 0):

Split the collection of the strings into an array first

```
var array = collectionOfStrings.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

> If there's a collection of strings separated by spaces that come from STDIN , how would I add them to a Map().

Split the input string and then `reduce` into a `Map`, like this:

```js
const input = 'aa bb cc bb aa';
const allWords = input.split(' ');
const wordsMap = allWords.reduce((accumMap, word) => {
  const wordCount = accumMap.get(word) || 0;
  accumMap.set(word, wordCount + 1);
  return accumMap;
}, new Map());
console.log(wordsMap.get('aa') + '\n\n');

// Iterate through them with:
for ([word, wordCount] of wordsMap.entries()){
  console.log([word, wordCount]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string.

To catch all spaces (space, newline, tabs, etc...) use a regex with the [`\s` (white spaces)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-white-space):

> Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form
>   feed, line feed. Equivalent to [
>   \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff].

**Example:**

```js
const txt = `give me one grand today night
give one grand today`

console.log(txt.split(/\s+/));
```